# Flutter: RouteAware triggers only didPush event

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

Hello i'm new to flutter and although i have already searched on this topic, it is unclear to me. So here is the code:

main.dart file

```
RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await DotEnv().load('.env');
  final UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
  runApp(BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc(userRepository)..add(AppStarted()),
    child: App(
      userRepository: userRepository
    ),
  ));
}
```

profile_form.dart (is on another file and imports the routeObserver from main.dart)

```
class ProfileForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  final User _user;

  ProfileForm(
      {Key key, @required UserRepository userRepository, @required User user})
      : assert(userRepository != null && user != null),
        _userRepository = userRepository,
        _user = user,
        super(key: key);
  State<ProfileForm> createState() => _ProfileFormState();
}

class _ProfileFormState extends State<ProfileForm> with RouteAware {

  UserRepository get _userRepository => widget._userRepository;
  User get _user => widget._user;

  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    print('didPush FirstPage');
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    print('didPopNext FirstPage');
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    print('didPop FirstPage');
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    print('didPushNext FirstPage');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("dis");
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

This form is entered through the Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
Although the trigger of didPush() event fires when i go back to another page (again from Nanigator or back button) and waiting for the didPop() event to fire it does not. What do i miss here? My main problem is that i want to save changes when the user exits the profile screen but before entering the init of another screen.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem so if this can help anyone, here's what caused it. The problem was that the `RouteObserver` that the `RouteAware` was subscribing to, was a different one from the one that was used by `MaterialApp`.

So the `RouteObserver` in `MaterialApp` was checking `didPush` & `didPop` events, but didn't have any listeners. The reason that you still get a `didPush` event, is because the observer always sends a `didPush` when you `subscribe`.

The root cause in our case, was that we used a `Provider` to provide the `RouteObserver` to the `RouteAware` widget, but everytime the `MaterialApp` was rebuilt, it got a new `RouteObserver` different from the one created by the provider.

Check if the `RouteObserver` you are subscribing to is the same one that's being used by `MaterialApp`, using the `hashCode` property!

Comment: I believe I hit the same exact problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281827/has-anything-changed-in-the-way-routeobservers-work-in-flutter  How did you eventually get around the problem?  Im not using providers but I am using a bottom navigation that I believe is setting up a new navigator route for each tab

Comment: it saved me couple of hours to debug